# Unable to install dlib in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, dlib

I am trying to install `dlib` in Anaconda so as to use it inside jupyter-notebook.

I tried using `conda install -c menpo dlib` and then dlib doesn't get installed rather it then says :

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
py-boost-1.67.0      | 318 KB    | ################################################################# | 100% 
widgetsnbextension-1 | 1.1 MB    |                                                                   |   0% 
ipywidgets-5.1.5     | 61 KB     |                                                                   |   0% 
boost-1.59.0         | 11.9 MB   |                                                                   |   0% 
dlib-19.9            | 2.3 MB    |                                                                   |   0% 

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/osx-64/widgetsnbextension-1.2.3-py35_1.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/osx-64/ipywidgets-5.1.5-py35_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/osx-64/boost-1.59.0-py35_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/menpo/osx-64/dlib-19.9-py35_0.tar.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
```

---

Then, I downloaded the `dlib-19.16.0.tar.gz` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/dlib/19.6.0/#files) and saved it in                 `/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages` and then ran `conda install -c conda-forge dlib-19.16.0.tar.gz` but it shows :

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - dlib-19.16.0.tar.gz

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error is just saying you are not able to connect to the menpo repository of libraries. I recommend to check your proxy/internet connection.

In the second case you are trying to install a tar.gz file, that's a compressed file. Decompressed it(unzip it) first and then try to install it.

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge dlib-19.16.0` says the same thing after extracting the tar file.

Comment: Download the wheel, the .whl file, and try to install it that way. Make sure your Python version and OS are the correct ones as that wheel is for Python 3.6 and Windows 64 bits.

Btw, the tar file is still a compressed file. So if you unzip it then you will be able to see the setup.py file and all the other components of the dlib library. Using the setup.py you will be able to install the library but in order to do that you need a cpp compiler, etc so I just recommend you to install it using the wheel provided in that link.